# How do I call an external ArrayList from an actionPerformed?

Tags: java

I have 4 comboBox where I want to put an object in the same ArrayList after I press the button. How can I do it?

```
        JButton btnRealizarPedido = new JButton("Realizar pedido");
            btnRealizarPedido.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    //GestorPedido.crearPedido(aProductos, aCliente)
                }
            });

            btnRealizarPedido.setBounds(20, 220, 150, 30);
            contentPane.add(btnRealizarPedido);


            jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                }
            });
            jComboBox1.setBounds(120, 60, 58, 30);
            contentPane.add(jComboBox1);
```

The ArrayList is in the main of this JFrame

Answer (score 1):

If the ArrayList is public then you should be able to access it anywhere within the same class. If its not in the same class then you may have to make a constructor with the ArrayList as a parameter like so:

```
public class Main()
{
    public Main(ArrayList<Something>)
    {
    }
}
```

You should then be able to create a new instance of that class and pass in your ArrayList, next time however, make sure to show all of the code for clarity purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The `actionPerformed` method is a method of an anomymous subclass of `ActionListener`. Within the `actionPerformed` method, `this` refers to its enclosing instance, in this case `ActionListener`. If you want to refer to a field of your subclass of JFrame, then you need to [qualify `this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4).

In order to do that, you must put the enclosing class before it:

```
MyJFrame.this.myArrayList.add(...);
```